# First index (0) of DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

My OnSelectedIndexChanged method is not firing when selecting the first item from the dropdown list.

When selecting any other index, the method works as it should, but when selecting index 0, my ddl_OnSelectedIndexChanged is never even called.

Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dll_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Code:

```
protected void dll_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddl.SelectedIndex == 0 || ddl.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

Populating ddl:

```
private void fillDropDownList()
    {
        List<string> ddlList = new List<string>();
        ddlList.Add("");

        //filing the rest of the list with strings

        ddl.DataSource = ddlList;
        ddl.DataBind();
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fillDropDownList();

    }
```

Comment: If you switch from index 0 to index 0? In that case you don't change your index

Comment: No, I switch from whichever index to 0, still doesnt trigger the event. Every other combination works as expected.